# When pushViewController, new viewcontroller seems draw in background instead of front

Tags: ios

The first ViewController is inherited from UINavigationController, and there is a tableview in it. My second ViewController is just a empty page, with red color as background for test convenience. And when click a table row, push next page:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    SecondViewController * SecondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"ViewControllers before pushing: %@", self.viewControllers);
    [self pushViewController:SecondVC animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"ViewControllers after pushing: %@", self.viewControllers);
}
```

The log shows that the push succeeded. but the problem is the new ViewController looks like in the background. I can only see some part of the red color.

Any idea what is wrong?

Update: if I put the pushViewController code in button click callback, it works well. just dont work in the tableview's row select callback.

Comment: What is this line: `[self SecondVC animated:YES];` ? Did you mean `[self pushViewController:SecondVC animated:YES];` ? And what do you mean exactly by saying that you have tableview in UINavigationController?

Comment: Leszek: yes, I mean [self pushViewController:SecondVC animated:YES], its my typo in the question.  The first ViewController is a UINavigationController, and contains a tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find the reason, the first Controller is defined as:

```
@interface FirstVC : UINavigationController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

UINavigationController just does not work in this way, after change to below. it works.
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use  `pushViewController:animated:` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:)